# Is there a free cloud storage app to install on my server?

Tags: online-storage

I am looking for a free web application to manage cloud storage so that I can install it on my web server and serve client requests? Let's say I want to have my own Dropbox (on my own domain like example.com). That way I will have complete control over files and storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) or [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/). Both are quite similar as Nextcloud is a fork of OwnCloud.

Comment: Are these open-source web apps?

Comment: @JasonStack Yes, both are FOSS afaik.